# Notice: Undefined variable: eventDispatcher?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4, symfony-2.1

Hey brothers I'm stack in this problem I'm trying to make and event to send email to any new user done his registration but I don't know what's wrong

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please **never** put pictures of code in questions.  Cut and paste on text works perfectly.  In the editor, format code with the `{ }` icon on top.  Read [ask] and [mcve] for expectations on questions.

Comment: hey thank you so  much i will but just i wanna know while there is ability to share images why not? else why there is input file to browse images ?

Comment: Images are great to show the interface used, or the graph produced, ...  But for code, it is much better to put it as text.  See this post for more details: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally do not want to create a new event dispatcher instance in your controller. When doing so your controller would also be responsible for attaching all the listeners which quite contradicts the loose coupling between the code dispatching an event and the parts of your application listening to these events.

Instead you will probably want to use the `event_dispatcher` service. In modern Symfony applications all you need to do is to add an extra argument to your controller action that is type-hinted with the `EventDispatcherInterface` (just like you are already doing it with the password encoder):

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

public function registerAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right about injecting the event dispatcher instead of creating one. To be honest it was late at night and the question provided images instead of code so I could not copy paste the controller declaration to add the dependency. :P

Comment: hhhhh thank you too even the message didnt sent hhh i rested from errors but now its good good job guys god bless you all

Answer (score 1):

You should create an EventDispatcher object before using it:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
....
public function registerAction(..., EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
{

    $event = new GenericEvent($user);
    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(Events::USER_REGISTERED, $event);
}
```

**EDIT**:  xabbuh is right. My code block assumed you have added your registration listeners to the dispatcher. Indeed, this prevents the decoupling that EventDispatcher component tries to provide. Furthermore, one shouldn't create objects in controller using `new` whenever possible, using dependency injection and/or factory pattern instead.

In your case, you should inject the EventDispatcher service (through EventDispatcherInterface) in your controller, using autowiring by type-hinting like above.

Comment: but still the message dont go .while  when i use cli the swift mailer work very good and send mails do u think i missed somthing ?

Comment: You should first check if onUserRegistrated function is executed as expected. If it does, I guess the problem is about swiftmailer configuration.

Comment: heyy bro thank you so much its work good perfectly i just made new instance inside the controller it was wrong the right way its use injection of dependency as u notice thank you so much again you are great keep going